# How do I compare two Apache Arrow RecordBatches with arrow-rs?

Tags: rust, apache-arrow

I have a two `Vec<arrow::record_batch::RecordBatch>` and I want to compare them.

I want to compare their schemas and their contents.

They might be partitioned into batches differently, which should not matter.

Ideally, I want to see the reason for comparison failure, something like `assert_eq!()` macro.

Comment: Can you give an example what the edge cases are your are facing when using the default eq implementation? Can you give a minimal working example showing the problems you face?